Creating Cognito UserPool users fails with Pulumi albeit successful with AWSSDK
I'm trying to create users to a UserPool but constantly getting Attributes did not conform to the schema: User: The attribute User is not defined in schema., which is strange, because when I'm doing the same with  AWSSDK and it's working.
This is the Pulumi failing code:
new User($"cognito_user_one", new() {
    UserPoolId = "us-west-1_grltah6jd",
    Username = "one@example.com",
    Password = "132134",
    Attributes = new InputMap<string> {
        ["dev:custom:UserType"] = "1"
    },
})

(the error is creating Cognito User (us-west-1_grltah6jd/one@example.com): InvalidParameterException: Attributes did not conform to the schema: User: The attribute User is not defined in schema.)
And this is the working AWSSDK code:
await client.AdminCreateUserAsync(new AdminCreateUserRequest {
    UserPoolId = "us-west-1_grltah6jd",
    Username = "one@example.com",
    TemporaryPassword = "132134",
    UserAttributes = [
        new() { Name = "dev:custom:UserType", Value = "1" }
    ],
    MessageAction = "SUPPRESS"
})

CloudTrail shows some difference between these two calls, but I can't see the content, as it's replacing it to HIDDEN_DUE_TO_SECURITY_REASONS. Here is the failing Pulumi's entry in CloudTrail (only the relevant part):
    "errorCode": "InvalidParameterException",
    "errorMessage": "Attributes did not conform to the schema: User: The attribute User is not defined in schema.",
    "requestParameters": {
        "userPoolId": "us-west-1_grltah6jd",
        "username": "HIDDEN_DUE_TO_SECURITY_REASONS",
        "userAttributes": "HIDDEN_DUE_TO_SECURITY_REASONS",
        "forceAliasCreation": false
    },

And this is the equivalent CloudTrail part from the successful AWSSDK call:
    "requestParameters": {
        "userPoolId": "us-west-1_grltah6jd",
        "username": "HIDDEN_DUE_TO_SECURITY_REASONS",
        "userAttributes": "HIDDEN_DUE_TO_SECURITY_REASONS",
        "temporaryPassword": "HIDDEN_DUE_TO_SECURITY_REASONS",
        "forceAliasCreation": false,
        "messageAction": "SUPPRESS"
    },

Any idea what am I'm doing wrong?
